# In Vue&Vuex, how can I activate onclick method in child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to edit JS library that already existed but it consisted of Vue. So I studied Vue a little. 
The problem is that I made child component called 'Analysis' and want to anchor function. I made  tag and bind 'moveAnchor' method to onclick, also  declared 'moveAnchor' on methods part. but it didn't work. How can I fix? I'm sorry for being inexperienced.. :(

it is script.js of analysis.

```
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
  name: 'Analysis',
  computed: {
    checkName : function(){
      var flag = this.$store.state.analysis.name;
      if(flag.indexOf("/PCs/") != -1){
        console.log(flag);
      }
  }
  },
  methods: {
    moveAnchor: function (id){
      var div = document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView();
  }
```

it is template.html of analysis.

```
<div :class="$style.scrollarea">
 <div :class="$style.dropdown">
      <button :class="$style.dropbtn">Analysess</button>
 <div :class="$style.dropContent">
 <a v-for="item in analyData" v-bind:key="item.id" @onclick="moveAnchor(item.id)">
  {{ item.title }}
 </a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <span>
      {{ checkName }}
 </span>
 <div v-for="item in analyData">
      <h1 v-bind:id="item.id">{{ item.title }}</h1>
      <img v-bind:src="item.src" style="width: 100%; height: auto">
 </div>
```

Comment: Did you try `@click`, `v-on:click` instead of `@onclick`?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange!

The correct binding for Vue's click event is `v-on:click`, or `@click` for shorthand. So when you write `@onclick`, Vue will never call that.

Just change `@onclick` to `@click` and all should work fine.